# continue-on-error inside action (not inside workflow)

Tags: github-actions

There is a `continue-on-error` option available for steps inside workflows.
I'd like to achieve the similar functionality but inside action.

That means that if a step has failed, I'd like to continue with next steps, being able to detect the failure.
Something like:

```yaml
name: Action (not a workflow!!!)
runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
    - id: action
      uses: ./something-that-may-fail
      continue-on-error: true
    - if: steps.action.outcome != 'success'
      run: foo/bar...
      shell: sh
```

How can anything like that be implemented?

Comment: If you're talking about composite actions, please update the title.

Comment: This should be implemented according to https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1457. Can you please share the error message you receive?